default export - is not a function
I'm currently working in a legacy project that's built using CommonJS. But because I needed to use react-pdf to create PDF files, I had to add .mjs files to my project.
This works fine on the dev environment, because I used:
require('@babel/register')({
    presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
});

But I can't use this in production, so now I need to transpile my code using webpack. And when I run this transpiled code, I get this error:
center_ is not a function
When looking at the file that uses this center_, I see that this is an .mjs file.
This is the relevant piece of code that causes this issue:
import center from '@turf/center';

let testVar = center(boundingBoxPolygon);

This should work, but when I look at the bundled & transpiled code, I see this:
var center_ = __webpack_require__("@turf/center");
var testVar = center_(boundingBoxPolygon);

But the center function from @turf returns an object with a default function:
{ default: [Function: center] }

So it seems that the bundled code is trying to invoke the object instead of the default function.
Is this a mistake in my settings, or is this a bug in webpack or babel?
Does anyone know how I can fix this?
This is my webpack config:
const path = require('path');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {
    target: 'node',
    externals: [nodeExternals()],
    entry: {
        'server': './src/server/index.js',
        'server.prod': './server.prod.js',
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'dist', 'server'), // Output directory
        filename: '[name].js',
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
    },
    optimization: {
        moduleIds: 'named',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(mjs|js)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
                    },
                },
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.mjs', '.js', '...'],
    },
};

